# unable to view output on screen

Tags: python, flask

my code is as follows :

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'OMTSL_QBO'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Welcome to Python Flask App!"

@app.route("/Authenticate")
def Authenticate():
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) from REPORT_SUITE")
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    print data    
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

i am unable to view the count on screen . The error i am getting is TypeError: 'long' object is not callable.. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return string or response from flask view function and since you are returning `long` type flask is complaining. Learn more about responses [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#about-responses).

In your case it'll be enough to do `return str(data)`.